# Anaphor resolution in Python

Tags: python, linux, nlp

I want to use Anaphor resolution in my project related to text mining. I am doing the project on the Linux platform and I am using Python. I have searched on net but there is no appropriate toolkit which can perform anaphora resolution in Python. Please suggest some toolkit which can do so.

I want to find the noun of the pronoun. for e.g

> Joey was having lunch. He was too hungry.

I want the "He" in next sentence to be replaced by"Joey".

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the docs for [NLTK-DRT](http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/sem/drt.html#resolve_anaphora).

Comment: i have tried that.Is there any other package like gtar,bart in python?